# MSVS 2015 puts errno in stddef.h?

Tags: c, visual-c++

I have a project that is compiled on multiple platforms, one of them Visual C++. What I noticed is that we often break the build because a developer has used errno without including errno.h, but because they work in Visual Studio, and their source includes stddef.h, either directly or indirectly, it did not fail to compile for them.

Why is errno defined in this header? What is a good way to catch this problem early in our cycle, i. e. still inside Visual Studio?

Comment: In your project put the cursor on the `errno` symbol, press F12 and VS will show you where the symbol is defined. That's a start.

Comment: I'm trying to get a compilation failure for when errno.h was forgotten.

Comment: Other header can include `<errno.,h>` which is why it works. There's no standard cross-platform way to check if a specific header has been included or not, especially since other header might include the file so it will in fact be included.

Comment: FYI: on my VS2013 `errno` is defined in stdlib.h. Besides if with the win32 SDK, errno is included via stdlib.h or whatever but not on another platform, I don't think you can do much about it.

Comment: Having one platform compile code that all others fail is super annoying. I am always trying to keep them as similar as possible, to avoid build-and-fix cycles after the code hits the CI servers. This is one of the more egregious cases where all compilers are not alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is a good way to catch this problem early in our cycle, i. e. still inside Visual Studio?

Problems like this are very hard, if not impossible, to catch unless you are developing simultaneously on two different platforms.

You could search for the string "errno" in all the files in VS project and then check whether the search also finds "errno.h" but that will be useful only for this particular issue. The standard library has many other functions/macros that may be indirectly visible to you. It's not practical to use the same strategy for making sure that right header files is `#include`d for all the functions/macros.

A disciplined developer and/or peer review of code might be your best options to address the issue.

Comment: I think you're probably right. I would prefer that this already happens at compilation time, but a separate test that scans files for the errno string and checks that errno.h is included by them is another solution. If developers run tests before they commit, as they should (we haven' enforced it by commit rules yet), then this should save them. Code reviews happen later in our process (after the code has gone through the CI server, and the bug has already cost the developer's time), so that's not going to work.